# Is \@ and \- needed in crefname?

Tags: cleveref

Using cleveref I sometimes write stuff such as

```
\documentclass[deutsch,graybox,envcountchap]{svmono}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,british,canadian,latin,russian,french,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefname{example}{Bsp.\@}{Bei\-spie\-le}
\Crefname{example}{Beispiel}{Bei\-spie\-le}
\crefname{exercise}{Übg.\@}{Übgn.\@}
\Crefname{exercise}{Übung}{Übun\-gen}
....
```

My questions are:

- Do I need to put `\@` after the periods to say that the abbreviations are in general not at the end of a sentence or would cleveref do it for me?
- Do I need to specify the hyphenation points explicitly via `\-`, given that the main document language is modern German, or would cleveref simply allow for hyphenation assuming modern German?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You probably do not need the explicit hyphenation points. Why do you need german and ngerman?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- If the babel package is loaded with the `german` and/or `ngerman` language options, `\frenchspacing` is in force by default, meaning that it's redundant to write `Bsp.\@` instead of just `Bsp.`: there won't be any extra space after sentence-ending periods anyway. See the first three lines in the screenshot shown below.
- If you pass the option `ngerman` to the `cleveref` package, it's not necessary to specify a German-language form for the label that goes with the `example` env./counter, unless you prefer using somewhat idiosyncratic abbreviated forms.
- As the following screenshot also demonstrates, LaTeX manages to find all standard hyphenation points in the words "Beispiele" and "Übungen", *if* the `ngerman` language option is in force. (The vertical markers, highlighted in yellow, are inserted by the `showhyphens` package -- compile the code with LuaLaTeX).

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{example}{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Übung}
\crefname{example}{Bsp.}{Beispiele} % the "Bsp." abbrev. is a bit nonstandard
\crefname{exercise}{Übg.}{Übgn.}
\Crefname{exercise}{Übung}{Übungen}

\begin{document}
\begin{example} \label{exp:a} aaa \end{example}
\begin{exercise}\label{exc:b} bbb \end{exercise}
\begin{example} \label{exp:c} ccc \end{example}
\begin{exercise}\label{exc:d} ddd \end{exercise}

\noindent
\cref{exp:a}, \cref{exc:d}.

\noindent
Bsp.\ 1, Übg.\ 2.

\noindent
Bsp. 1, Übg. 2. % just to demonstrate that '\frenchspacing' is in effect

\noindent
\Cref{exp:a,exp:c} und \Cref{exc:b,exc:d}.
\end{document}
```